# Query using SharePoint REST API using Author/EMail

Tags: sharepoint-online

I running into an issue with filtering using the Autor/EMail field in REST API. The query works fine when the List in Not Throttled. But we get Throttling exception when the List is throttled (>5000). The Created By Column is Indexed was well.

```
https://example.org/sites/dev/rnd/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Favs')/items?$Select=ID,ItemId,ListName,Author/EMail&$Expand=Author&$Filter=Author/EMail eq 'john.smith@org.com'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After couple of trial and error I found that Author/Email is not the correct field to use. Instead we need to use Author/Id. The Id would the site user id and we can get the value from the property _spPageContextInfo.userId

Hope this helps somebody.